# Erasing part of picture using GNU Octave

Tags: image-processing, octave

For the following image: how would you erase the tree from the picture (using GNU Octave code), leaving only the grass and the sky? Is this possible? If so, how could I do it?

Image: http://tinyurl.com/7uttjzg

Answer (score 0):

You have invested almost whole reputation of yours. I was not having much knowledge about GNU Octave initially. I studied it for your devotion. I might not able to give full-fledged answer. But some hints might help you.

1. You will need to make sections of image by using `imagesc` and 'caxis'. For more information see this [Displaying-Images](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Displaying-Images.html#doc-imagesc) and [Axis-Configuration](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Axis-Configuration.html#doc-caxis)
2. Do appropriate [color conversion](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Color-Conversion.html#Color-Conversion).
3. Then do proper seetings for `Gamma`, `Matte`, `QuantizeColors` and [save image](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Loading-and-Saving-Images.html#Loading-and-Saving-Images).

See this [image-processing information](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Image-Processing.html).